# Ripple effect does not work after using bootstrap material design for in Yii2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, yii2-advanced-app, bootstrap-material-design

I'm trying to use [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIzAKSV34PU) for using Material Ripple in my yii2 advanced app.

And in the `Test.html` buttons and effects and ripples is working, but in my `Yii2` app the library is without any ripple effect.

this is my css's and other files:

[image]

**Material Asset:**

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class MaterialAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@themes/material';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/material.min.css',
        'css/material-fullpalette.min.css',
        'css/ripples.min.css',
        'css/roboto.min.css',
        'css/site.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/material.min.js',
        'js/ripples.min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: First, you only need `material.min.css` OR `material-fullpalette.min.css`, not both.  Second, you aren't showing any of the html generated.  Try creating a snippet [with this codepen](http://codepen.io/rosskevin/pen/VvRgrN) to determine your own problem or so we can help further.  Third, be sure to download the latest distribution, it's changing quickly!

Answer (score 0):

fixed with using this line in view:

```
$this->registerJs("$.material.init()");
```

thanks to Yii Irc guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you added all the necessary `css` and `js` but it still doesn't work. You might wanna load `arrive.js` before the `material-design.js`

Install using bower `bower install arrive --save`